# Declare option other than documentclass

Tags: etoolbox, options

I I have a `usrdefn.tex` file in which I defined some commends/environments used a lot, also there are two version of theorem environments based on the language (english/chinese). Then I want to pass an option to the `documentclass` and choose the block automatically. The mme looks like:

FOR CHINESE:

```
\documentclass[zh]{ctexart}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\input usrdefn
\begin{document}
 \begin{thm}
    中文定理
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

FOR ENGLISH

```
\documentclass[en]{amsart}
\begin{document}
\begin{thm}
 English Theorem
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

with the `usrdefn.tex`

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtoggle{langen}
\makeatletter
\DeclareOption{en}{\toggletrue{langen}}
\DeclareOption{zh}{\togglefalse{langen}}
\makeatother
\iftoggle{langen}{
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
}{
\newtheorem{thm}{定理}
}
```

This is not work, since it tells me that

> |4 error| \RequirePackage or \LoadClass in Options Section.

OK, I see, I need to `\ProcessOptions` after the `\DeclareOption` stuff, which solved my problem!!

Comment: do you want to add your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Better: use the structure of LaTeX 2ε by creating a personal package. 
Put this in a `usrdefn.sty` file (that you can keep in the current directory, or better, in the [standard places](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te)):

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1996/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{usrdefn}[2016/07/04 My personal macros v1.0]
\RequirePackage{etoolbox} % <- conventionally, use this and not \usepackage in .sty files
\newtoggle{langen}
\DeclareOption{en}{\toggletrue{langen}}
\DeclareOption{zh}{\togglefalse{langen}}
\ProcessOptions
\iftoggle{langen}{
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
}{
\newtheorem{thm}{定理}
}
```

You do not need `makeatletter` here (it's the default in `.sty` files).
Now you can use it in your main document as

```
\documentclass[en]{amsart}
\usepackage{usrdefn}
...
```

(Notice that class options "percolate" down to packages. You can also use `\usepackage[en]{usrdefn}` if you prefer).

Comment: Yes, in fact I know how to write it in a package, but I would prefer to use it directly(and more freely) instead to provide a package. But thanks for your response!